# Why does PauseToken break the task?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I'm trying to understand `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.PauseToken`.

When I have called `PauseTokenSource.Pause()`, the method is paused and the task is completed, and I can see "Completed" message.

After that I have called `PauseTokenSource.Resume()`, and the task is continued.
But I have no message when the process has finished.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I fix it?

I want `PauseToken` to not break the task during the work. I don't want to get the message after pause. I want to get message at true end of process.

```
public PauseToken PauseToken;

private async Task DoDoneAsync()
{
    FlagCommandDone = true;

    try
    {
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                double i = 0;
                while (i < 3)
                {
                    i++;
                    await PauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        );
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        isError = true;
        message = e.Message;
    }

    if (!isError) message = task.IsCompleted ? "Completed" : "Canceled";

    MessageBox.Show(message);

    FlagCommandDone = false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    double i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        i++;
        CurrentStatus = i.ToString();
        var a = (int)(double)((i / 3.0) * 100.0);
        MessageBox.Show(PauseToken.IsPaused.ToString());
        await PauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
        CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        CurrentProgress = a;
    }
}
, CancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code is that the task created by `StartNew()` is deemed complete when the invoked method returns. And of course, it being an `async` method with an `await`, that method returns as soon as the first `await` is executed on an incomplete task.

So, your `DoDoneAsync()` method is in fact completing before the whole you thought you were starting completes. It essentially is waiting only until your `StartNew()` method reaches its first `await`.

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it's impossible to know for sure what will fix your program. But, I think the main thing is to stop trying to mix blocking code with async code. Instead, just factor the anonymous method you have invoked by `StartNew()` out into its own named method, make it properly async, and just call it directly.

For example:

```
private async Task DoDoneAsync()
{
    FlagCommandDone = true;

    try
    {
        await DoDoneLoopAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        isError = true;
        message = e.Message;
    }

    if (!isError) message = task.IsCompleted ? "Completed" : "Canceled";

    MessageBox.Show(message);

    FlagCommandDone = false;
}

private async Task DoDoneLoopAsync()
{
    double i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        i++;
        await PauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... I don't understand a little. And why do DoDoneLoopAsync works? If await PauseToken.WaitWhilePausedAsync will be complited, it means the whole method shall be complited, because the first await will be executed. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I saw. It's all about Task.Factory.StartNew. But I need its, because I want to use ProgresBar. And I need new thread. Also I need CancellationToken. I updated post, I added properties of ProgressBar and CancellationToken. Can I use standart PauseToken in task or I need write own token without await?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would suggest a need for a new thread, nor the use of a `ProgressBar`, and certainly there is nothing about `ProgressBar` that _implies_ a need for a new thread or the use of `TaskFactory.StartNew()`. The above answers the question you asked. If you have a different problem, such as figuring out how to apply the above to a broader scenario, you can post that as a new question. Make sure you provide a good [mcve] in that question, that shows clearly and completely what you're trying to do and what specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't like your solution, but in any case, thanks. The solution was found.

Comment: Suit yourself. As they say, "you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink". If you want your code to remain inferior, that's your prerogative.

Comment: I hope your code will help me in future, but now I have no purpose to create super optimized app. As I wrote, I had purpose to learn PauseToken in my code and understand why did not it work? You help me, thank you. May be your code is more optimized for app than other, I don't know. I'll decide it later. But now I have enough advice from VladD. I like to understand all step by step. And in my opinion you should not be decided that my code will remain inferior or not, because you don't know my minds and don't see all code. As I said, any case, thank you for your advise.

Comment: _"in my opinion you should not be decided that my code will remain inferior or not"_ -- it's not really a matter of opinion. Your approach, starting a task to perform work that doesn't need a task is _objectively_ inferior to doing the same work without starting a task. But again, if that's how you want your code, feel free.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use `Task.Run()` instead `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Thanks to [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762660/264402).